# How to create an sortable grid in xamarin?

Tags: sorting, listview, xamarin, uwp, grid

I'm working on a **Xamarin PCL** project and I have a page with currently an listview in it. The listview contains class items that are added later trough binding. The class items contain a grid with all the information. In this project we only implement with **C#**. Not XAML. The project is available for **Android** and **UWP**, but this is only an **UWP** feature.

I'm looking to implement something that has multiple columns with each a header. The header needs to be clickable so that the list can be sorted on the headers property.

I'm thinking about a grid but that doesn't have a sort function. Any idea how to implement this?

Below is an example how we need it. (Product, Kw1, Kw2 and eindtotaal are clickable and the list are sortable on these headers)
[Example](https://support.content.office.net/nl-nl/media/3dd2b79b-9160-403d-9967-af893d17b580.png)

Comment: Take a look at [DataGrid CTP](https://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui/datagrid) by Telerik

Comment: Thanks, I will look into DataGrid CTP. Unfortunately I was lokking for something free to use (instead of a free trail) so I'm thinking about a new grid with clickable cells and a new sort function. Thnx anyway VijayNirmal and Scavenger